# Таймер в часах/минутах/секундах на python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, таймер

Нужна утилита отсчитывающая время до выполнения функции, но не в секундах, а в часах и минутах.
Думал реализовать умножая секунды на 60, сохранять в минутную переменную, потом её же ещё на 60, получая часовую, но чёт такое себе решение как мне кажется.
В модуле Time нужной инфы не нашёл.
Таймеров несколько, все они в отдельных потоках и нужно выводить оставшееся время в Label на tkinter.

Comment: Непонятно чем умножение не угодило

Comment: Только не умножение,  а деление

Comment: Отсчет минут и часов по секундам через умножение - нормальная практика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

обычно делается так:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = time // 3600, (time - 3600 * (time // 3600)) // 60, time % 60
```

или так

```
hours, minutes, seconds = time // 3600, (time % 3600) // 60, time % 60
```